# How to run a docker container which acts as a proxy/gateway?

Tags: docker

I'm currently trying to set up an environment of 2 docker containers which are running simultaneously. One container should act as a default gateway/proxy. The other system is performing some actions which result in network traffic which should be automatically routed to the default gateway.

I'v tried to create the following network:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.0.0.0/24 --iprange=10.0.0.0/24 --gateway=10.0.0.1 br0
```

When running container-1 with that network the machine will get IP 10.0.0.2, container-2 will get IP 10.0.0.3. When checking the route on any machine, the default gateway is set to 10.0.0.1. I tried to set the default gateway manually on container-2 but I always get an error that I don't have privileges to do so (even as root user).

I need container-1 to be the gateway (ip 10.0.0.1).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `--privileged` option when starting your containers. This gives them the privileges to use commands such as the one to set the default gateway.